# How to Interactively ask a user to change Permissions for a Specified File

Tags: bash, permissions, read, write

**I need to create a script that will allow a specified file to have its permissions changed interactively by asking the user if they would like to enable Read, Write and/or Execute one by one for each of the three areas of permissions. Once the new permissions are determined, they need to be applied to the file.**

I've spent over an hour researching how I would even start to go about writing a script for this and have had no luck. This seems a bit too complex for me but I'd like to learn how to do this and would appreciate any advice that would guide me in the right direction of how this script might look.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SX. You should probably provide us with what you have tried so far. From what you say, you should have a look at `chmod` for permissions, and `dialog` for the interactions.

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. Does the course include other resources that would suggest what the interaction should look like? Will this run in a console/terminal emulator environment, or one with graphics? Does the assignment say whether the script should be supplied a filename as an argument or ask for its name interactively? What utilities besides the shell have you been taught to use? chmod? ls? read? echo? getopt?

Comment: It will run in the terminal environment, and the filename will be asked interactively. The commands that we have been taught do include chmod, read, echo, find, grep, and any other more intro to UNIX commands.

Comment: I know how to prompt the user for the input, as well as supply the proper error checking. I'm stuck on how I would then allow them to interactively change each of the permissions for the 3 groups. I have a feeling the sudo command will need to be used as well.

Comment: OK. The man page for chmod is not very clear, but you can invoke it like this: `chmod u=perms,g=perms,o=perms filename`, where `perms` is any or all of `r`, `w`, and `x`. Possibly the assignment wants you to store the user's choices for the three permission areas in shell variables, say `userperms`, `groupperms`, and `otherperms`, then run `chmod` with those variables substituted into the right places in that `u=...` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you get caught using this...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Did user supply an argument (path to folder?)
if [ "${1}" == "" ] ; then
  echo "Directory path required as argument" && exit 1
fi

# Was the arg a valid directory?
if [ ! -d "${1}" ] ; then
  echo "Directory argument was invalid" && exit 1
fi

# Re assign variable
dir="${1}"

# Get a list of files in directory
files=$(ls ${dir})

# Loop over files and ask questions
while file in "${files}" ; do

  # Prompt user for permissions to be set on user/group/owner
  read -p "Set permission for (u)ser/(g)roup/(o)wner? [u|g|o]" who

  # Prompt user for read/write/execute permission to be set
  read -p "Add read/write/execute to ${file}? [r|w|x]" ans

  # Set the specified permission for the specified account type
  chmod ${who}=${ans} ${file}

done
```

It really should present a loop to apply multiple account type read/write/execute bits per file but its late.